# java.lang.AbstractMethodError while running jersey project

Tags: java, maven, jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs

I am getting this exception while running Jersey project

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:293)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
```

Dependency in the pom is as follows :

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.22</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

while compiling using maven it is giving error as follows :

Project ID: unknown:hk2-parent

Reason: Invalid JDK version in profile 'javadoc-jdk8+': Unbounded range: [1.8 for project unknown:hk2-parent

Comment: Are you sure you want `<scope>import</scope>`? I would expect scope to be compile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% sure that you have both *com.sun.jersey* and *org.glassfish.jersey* in your dependencies. Thats wrong, don't do that. Try running a maven dependency tree with:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If you not found anything suspicious also try:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

Also don't use import scope but compile.

Also check that you are using JAX-RS 2 with *org.glassfish.jersey*.

Comment: I have checked whole project. I didn't find any com.sun.jersey dependency. But while compiling it is giving error [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: unknown:hk2-parent

Reason: Invalid JDK version in profile 'javadoc-jdk8+': Unbounded range: [1.8 for project unknown:hk2-parent